# grep for string not preceded by another string

Tags: grep, regex

Is it possible, using grep, to search for instances of `John Smith` but exclude instances of `Mr John Smith`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This could be solved using a regular expression with negative lookbehind (which is experimentally supported in `grep` as pointed out by the comment from arrange):

```
$ grep -P '(?<!Mr )John Smith' file
```

Since the support is just experimental, you might want to use `perl` instead:

```
$ perl -nle 'print if /(?<!Mr )John Smith/' file
```

Comment: It is experimentally supported in *grep*: `echo $string | grep -P '(?<!Mr )John Smith'`.

Comment: @arrange Indeed. Thanks, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can execute

```
command | grep 'John Smith' | grep -v 'Mr John Smith'
```

Comment: Nice idea, but will not work if the line has `John Smith Mr John Smith John Smith`

Answer (score 2):

To use regular expressions, use ^ and $

```
grep "^John Smith$"
```

^ is match from the beginning $ is match from end.

The syntax will vary depending on what you are searching for in what file.

You can use regular expressions with sed, grep, awk ....

Example

```
bodhi@Ubuntu:~ cat file
Mr John Smith
John Smith
John
Smith

bodhi@Ubuntu:~ grep "^John Smith$" file
John Smith
```

Comment: The OP do not ask for the string to be the only thing on its line.